# Adding parameters to IDbCommand

Tags: c#, datatable

I am creating a small helper function to return a `DataTable`. I would like to work across all providers that `ADO.Net` supports, so I thought about making everything use `IDbCommand` or `DbCommand` where possible.

I have reached a stumbling block with the following code:

```
    private static DataTable QueryImpl(ref IDbConnection conn, String SqlToExecute, CommandType CommandType, Array Parameters)
    {
        SetupConnection(ref conn);
        // set the capacity to 20 so the first 20 allocations are quicker...
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = SqlToExecute;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType;
            if (Parameters != null && Parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                for (Int32 i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(Parameters.GetValue(i));
                }
            }
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

When this code is executed, I receive an `InvalidCastException` which states the following:

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects.

The code falls over on the line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(Parameters.GetValue(i));
```

Any ideas?

Any improvements to the above code is appreciated.

---

Actual solution:

```
    private static readonly Regex regParameters = new Regex(@"@\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static DataTable QueryImpl(ref DbConnection conn, String SqlToExecute, CommandType CommandType, Object[] Parameters)
    {
        SetupConnection(ref conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = SqlToExecute;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType;
            if (Parameters != null && Parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                MatchCollection cmdParams = regParameters.Matches(cmd.CommandText);
                List<String> param = new List<String>();
                foreach (var el in cmdParams)
                {
                    if (!param.Contains(el.ToString()))
                    {
                        param.Add(el.ToString());
                    }
                }
                Int32 i = 0;
                IDbDataParameter dp;
                foreach (String el in param)
                {
                    dp = cmd.CreateParameter();
                    dp.ParameterName = el;
                    dp.Value = Parameters[i++];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(dp);
                }
            }
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Thanks for ideas/links etc. :)

Comment: What does Parameters.GetValue do?

Comment: @Dismissile, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getvalue.aspx

Comment: Nice actual solution.  However, setting DateTime.Now to DateTime field in MS Access/OleDb fails.

Comment: I heard the solution to avoid DateTime error is to set milliseconds to zero and that will solve the data type mismatch error.  Is that true? (I care about MS Access and SQL Server right now).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I believe IDbCommand has a CreateParameter() method:

```
var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@SomeName";
parameter.Value = 1;

command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Answer (score 50):

You could add the code of the accepted answer to an extension method:

```cs
public static class DbCommandExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AddParameter (this IDbCommand command, string name, object value)
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = name;
        parameter.Value = value;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not what you're asking, but I have a much simpler and more robust solution to offer.

The Microsoft Patterns and Practices library includes a Data Access Application block that is incredibly powerful and easy to use.  A sample for executing a stored procedure and returning a dataset is shown below from our actual code:

```
 object[] ParameterValues = new object[] {"1",DateTime.Now, 12, "Completed", txtNotes.Text};
 Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionStringName");
 DataSet ds =  = db.ExecuteDataSet("StoredProcName", ParameterValues);
```

It doesn't matter if the Connection is OleDb, ODBC, etc.  The ConnectionStringName in the first line of code is just the name of the Consternating as defined in the .config file.  You pass in a Connection String name, stored proc name, and an array of objects, which make up the parameters.
This is just one of the many sweet functions available.

You'll get everything you're trying to build and then some.

The official site is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx

To save you some searching, the Data classes documentation are found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data(PandP.50).aspx

(and it's free from Microsoft, and updated regularly.)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is intended for slightly more specific purpose than what you're doing, but building on **@Dismissile**'s answer, I used a `Dictionary` to supply the parameter name and value to a `foreach` loop in my personal project.

```
using( IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand() )
{
    dbCommand.CommandText = Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateCommand;
    Dictionary<string,object> values = new Dictionary<string,object>()
    {
        {"@param1",this.Property1},
        {"@param2",this.Property2},
        // ...
    };
    foreach( var item in values )
    {
        var p = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        p.ParameterName = item.Key;
        p.Value = item.Value;
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Parameters` parameter needs to be of type `IDataParameter[]` and, given the error text, the concrete implementation needs be a `SqlParameter[]` type.

If you wish to keep your signature, you'll need a factory to derive the necessary concrete implementation.

Comment: I'll be honest. Never used a factory, that I know of, wouldn't it just add complexity? Do you have any examples of a factory pattern?

Comment: @AustinSalonen Not using a parameter of type `IDataParameter[]` isn't the cause of the problem (although it would be preferable to accepting an `Array`). Also you do not need a factory to create the correct parameter type, as above, `IDbCommand` has a `CreateParameter` method - I'd recommend deleting this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Add `using System.Data.SqlClient;` and
`cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parameterName", value));`

Comment: -1'd, you are using a specific implementation when the rest of the code is clearly using IDbConnection. This is not the correct way to solve this problem.