# Applying query on textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net, textbox

i have 2 text boxes. the problem which i am facing is that when i enter a number in textbox1, the program should fetch the data from database and display the result in textbox2 but with out the use of any button. i have no idea which event to use. here is a code but i guess it is useless:

```
private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT item_name FROM prod_info WHERE barcode=" + textBox2.Text + "";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can respond to the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event on `textBox1` to trigger some action in your code.
Warning: be sure to [sanitize your inputs](http://xkcd.com/327/)!

Comment: This is correct, but he may find a small problem when changing the values, for example if the textbox is empty than the database may return an error. I mean that for every value that is changed the query will be executed and this may give a problem.

Comment: i did not get the last statment "Sanitize your input"

Comment: after entering the number in textbox1 i want it automatically to show the result in textbox 2.

Comment: @HaiderKhattak: Using the contents of a text box directly in the text of a database query is bad practice, and exposes you to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  All inputs must be _sanitized_ before inclusion in a query.

Comment: can you please correct the code or send me an type an example from which i can get an idea?

Comment: Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234971/adding-parameters-to-idbcommand).

Comment: Documentation and examples available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.data.idbcommand.parameters(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Search if there is any OnExit event, so after editing the first textbox the second will be updated automatically.

Comment: there is no OnExit event